# Debug an Individual C# Method in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Can I somehow run a single method in `C#` using `Visual Studio 2017` / `ReSharper` in order to debug it? I am aware that I can:

- Run the entire app and set a breakpoint (pain since I need to go through logic to get to method)
- Copy the method to a console app
- Run a unit test in debug mode on the method
- Go to some online C# pad (but then I need to duplicate all the using statements)

All of these are time consuming and I am wondering if there is some alternative.

EDIT: In SQL Management Studio, I can highlight an individual query and run it. I want some way to debug C# methods like this (obviously I would need to provide params for this). I haven't heard of anything like that, but it doesn't hurt to ask.

Comment: You don't have to set breakpoints in VS2017, you can run straight to where you point.

Comment: "pain since I need to go through logic to get to method" - how else do you want to tell Visual Studio WHICH method to debug? Weird question.

Comment: Unit tests? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532.aspx ; or on second though, add a project to your solution, add a reference to your original code, call the code however you want from your new project.

Comment: Once you have a unit test project set up, adding test for single methods takes no more than a minute or 2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the C# interactive window (it doesn't support debugging, but lets you quickly iterate on functions).

You can highlight chunks of code and then click on the `Execute in Interactive` menu item.

To use this effectively, you probably need to add some references and some using blocks to the interactive window.

To add a reference, you can use the `#r` command:

```
#r "System.Windows.Forms"
#r "C:\Full\Path\To\Your\Reference\Assembly.dll"
```

You can use using blocks from there using the normal syntax

```
using System.Windows.Forms
```

You can also declare and use objects within the scope of the interactive window:

```
var f = new Form();
f.ShowDialog();
```

If you ever need to cleanup your interactive window, you can use the reset command:

```
#reset
```

Comment: Looks like what I am looking for, thank you, trying now.

Comment: Can't believe it was 5 years since I asked this. If anyone else is looking at this, at the end of the day it's probably easier to use a unit/integration test if everything is set up for it, since you can quickly inject or mock dependencies. That's what I find myself doing.

Answer (score 4):

Make a call to that method a first thing in your application.